# What does “my six ounce” mean?

Tags: meaning

In the Netflix film *The Ballad of Buster Scruggs*, there is a tune called *When a Cowboy Trades his Spurs for Wings*, which contains these lines:

> When they wrap my body
>   In the thin linen sheet,
>   And they take ***my six ounce***
>   Pull the boots from my feet...

What does “my six ounce” mean here? I’ve searched for the phrase on the Internet and asked an American friend who is a native speaker, but with no result. Is “my six ounce” an established phrase in English?

Comment: A quick Google search of the previous line gives at least one YouTube video which has “and they take my six ***irons***”, which makes more sense (clearly a reference to guns).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a mishearing or transcription error.

Comment: By way of confirming the hypothesis put forward by Janus Bahs Jacquet, J. Taylor, and Paul F. elsewhere on this page, YouTube has an "[Official Lyric Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXna1a-806Q)" of "When A Cowboy Trades His Spurs For Wings," and at 1:14 of the video you can see the relevant lyric rendered as "and they take my six irons."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think it is "six ounce", but, rather, [six irons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K91etXNIkaY).

"Six irons" would be 6 round [revolvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver).

One hears what one hears, I might be in error, but, I do not think so.

Comment: Well, a man hears what he wants to hear and disregards the rest.

Comment: @Hot Licks... I agree that is often the case. I tried very hard to hear what was there.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wzUEL7vw60U

Comment: @Hot Licks...Simon and Garfunkel, not really my choice for listening, and, this rendition was somewhat distorted.

Comment: Oh, come now!  J. Taylor is built on Simon and Garfunkel!

Comment: @Hot Licks... If you are referring to another gentleman with a similar name who whines much like Simon and Garfunkel, OK. I prefer Handel and Bach, with no whining.

Comment: In a different context, "six irons" might be golf clubs.

Comment: @bof ... well, most people do not carry more than one 6 iron around with them.

Comment: @bof Perhaps, but it doesn't really make sense. Why would you have more than one 6-iron? Most golfers wouldn't talk like that.

Comment: it is most definitely “six irons”

Answer (score 1):

My Netflix captioning says "thin linen" and "six irons".  I hear "bindlin'" but "six irons" sounds like what actor Tim Blake Nelson is, in fact, saying.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought that he said 'six irons' as well. But, when you watch the movie with subtitles, it clearly says 'six ounces.' Maybe just a mistake on the end of the subtitler?

Also, in the scene where the banker is getting shot at and yelling "Pan shot!" the subtitles say 'Bad shot!' the first time and 'Pan shot!" every time after that. Looks to me like this is a bad transcription job.

(Watching on Netflix)

Comment: jdoe, without some authoritative source, the facts may not be known. Welcome toEnglish Language & Usage

Answer (score -2):

I think that they may be referring to his hat (Stetson approx. 6 ounces).   just a guess, but opposite end to boots

Comment: Thank you for your guess! I haven’t thought of a hat and it looks like you are right here.

Comment: I’m confused. This answer is rated -2, but it’s the right answer. What does that say about the reliability of voting merit?

Comment: He didn’t just like it. It’s objectively the correct answer, no? Surely there should be a difference.